# Scipy.minimize: how to calculate supremum with an epsilon

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, scipy-optimize, epsilon

I'm trying to determine the  supremum numerically of the following function:

> [image: sup function]

[example p(x) plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=plot+0%5C%2844%295+-+0%5C%2844%295*erf%5C%2840%290%5C%2844%295*%5C%2840%29Divide%5B10%2Csqrt%5C%2840%292%5C%2841%29%5D%5C%2841%29+*+log10%5C%2840%29Divide%5Bx%2C200%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29+from+x%3D0+to+600)

p(x) is a probability function with p(0+) > 0 which I further assume to be monotonic decreasing.

The problem is that experimenting with epsilon, I don't get a good value which I can verify with a table with some values.
Or rather, there is no fixed epsilon which gives the best result for all instances of p(x).

My approach was to use `scipy.optimize.minimize` to find the max value for my function.

```
def density_upper_scaled(alpha, sigma):
    epsilon = 0.1
    constraint = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint_function, 'args': (alpha, sigma)}
    guess = np.array([1])
    result = sp.optimize.minimize(density_upper_function, guess, bounds=[(epsilon, None)], constraints=constraint)
    max_value = -result.fun  

    return (1.437 * 200**2 / max_value)
#, {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: epsilon * x**2}

def density_upper_function(r):
    return - r**2 * 0.1


def constraint_function(r, alpha, sigma):
    return probability_function(r, alpha, sigma) - 0.1


def probability_function(distance, alpha, sigma):  
    ro0 = 200    # theoretical communication distance for sigma = 0
    if sigma != 0:
        p = 0.5 - 0.5 * math.erf((10 / math.sqrt(2)) * (alpha / sigma) * math.log10(distance / ro0))
    else:
        p = int(distance <= ro0)
    return p
```

My problem is that if epsilon is too small, minimize -> inf.

I then wanted to try this with a simple script myself which sometimes perform better but is worse for sigma/ alpha -> 0 with the following idea. Search for the highest x so that my p(x) is still greater equal my epsilon and the same for epsilon r**2.

```
condition = probability_function(x, alpha, sigma)
    prior = -1
    epsilon = 0.2
    while condition >= epsilon and condition * x ** 2 >= epsilon:
        prior = condition
        condition = round(probability_function(x, alpha, sigma),5)

        x += 1
    print (x, condition)
    print(x,condition, 200**2 * 1.437 / (condition * x **2) )
```

I've also tried to work with the second derivative to find x where the sign is flipped or take the value where it has a maximum but it also doesn't perfectly match the value I need.

Has anyone any idea where my error in thinking is or does anyone know of another method to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's create a MCVE to solve your problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize, special
```

We draw the probability function from your Wolfram link (feel free to change):

```
def p(r, alpha=10., sigma=np.sqrt(2.), r0=200):  
    return 0.5 - 0.5 * special.erf(0.5 * (alpha / sigma) * np.log10(r / r0))
```

Your model is therefore (where minus sign is to change supremum to infimum as we will minimize not maximize):

```
def model(x):
    # x = (epsilon, r)
    return - x[0] * np.power(x[1], 2.)
```

Without constraint, solution is indeed unbound. Now we add the following Non Linear Constraint:

```
def constraint(x):
    # x = (epsilon, r)
    return p(x[1]) - x[0]

nlc = optimize.NonlinearConstraint(constraint, 0., np.inf)
```

Time to bind everything:

```
solution = optimize.minimize(
     model, x0=[0., 1.],
     bounds=[(0., 1.), (0., np.inf)],
     constraints=[nlc]
)
```

Which returns a bound solution:

```
     fun: -19694.23466311135
     jac: array([-46597.57519531,   -182.46826172])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 31
     nit: 14
    njev: 10
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([  0.42264505, 215.86471535])
```

We can have a look on the solution to check out it's quality:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, with setting the upper bound for epsilon to 0.9 instead of 1, it behaves good and reaches my control values with a slight error for alpha/sigma >1 for p(x) with p(x) = 0.5 - 0.5 * special.erf( (alpha / sigma) * (10/ sqrt(2)) * np.log10(r / r0)). Otherwise the solution can set epsilon to 1, resulting in x running away into infinity